# Alphabetically Sort Structure Array

Tags: c++

so I have a structure array with various variables.

```
struct Data
{
    char name[11];
    int ID;
    int life;
    int date;
    float avgWindSpeed;
    float avgRainFall;
    int tornadoes;
    int stormCategory;
};
```

I am looking to sort all the information based on `char name[11]`. The data that is stored in `struct Data` comes from a file named `storms.txt`. Currently, I have everything to make up perfectly but still struggling with sorting everything alphabetically. Also, I named my `ofstream outfile` and `counter` contains the total number of storms inside the file.

My current code is:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Start of Hurricane Level 1
    int totalLevel1 = 0;    //Will hold the number of storms that are level 1


    //This is just setting the top part of the chart
    outfile << setw(70) << "Hurricane Level 1" << endl << endl;
    outfile << "Name" << setw(10) << "ID" << setw(20) << " Life  " << setw(20) << " Average  " << setw(20) << " Average " << setw(20) << "Tornadoes" << setw(19) << "  Date  " << endl;
    outfile << "    " << setw(10) << "  " << setw(20) << "in days" << setw(20) << "wind speed" << setw(20) << "rain fall" << setw(20) << " spawned " << setw(20) << "    " << endl;
    outfile << endl << endl;
    float avgLifeSpan, avgRainFall, avgTornadoes, avgWindSpeed, life = 0, rain= 0, tornado= 0, wind= 0;
    //Starting to process the information and printing it in its proper location
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        if(hurricanes[i].stormCategory == 1)
            {
                totalLevel1++;
                life = life + hurricanes[i].life;
                rain = rain + hurricanes[i].avgRainFall;
                tornado = tornado + hurricanes[i].tornadoes;
                wind = wind + hurricanes[i].avgWindSpeed;
                outfile << hurricanes[i].name << setw(5) << hurricanes[i].ID << setw(15) << hurricanes[i].life << setw(21) << hurricanes[i].avgWindSpeed 
                << setw(20) << hurricanes[i].avgRainFall << setw(19) << hurricanes[i].tornadoes << setw(21) << hurricanes[i].date << endl;
            }
    //Printing the extra information for HURRICANE LEVEL 1
    outfile << endl << endl << "Total number of Level 1 hurricanes is " << totalLevel1 << "." << endl;
    outfile << "Average Life span in days of Level 1 hurricanes is " << life / float(totalLevel1) << "." << endl;
    outfile << "Average rain fall for Level 1 hurricanes is " << rain / float(totalLevel1) << "." << endl;
    outfile << "Average tornadoes spawned for Level 1 hurricanes is " << tornado / float(totalLevel1) << "." << endl;
    outfile << "Average wind speed for Level 1 hurricanes is " << wind / float(totalLevel1) << "." << endl;
    outfile << endl << endl;

//End of the Hurricane Level 1
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to do I make so that everything that gets printed out on the output file is sorted alphabetically with its correct information? Could someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). It is a bit cryptic at first, but bottom like you can either write a `comp` (compare) function as specified or use a lamba function.

Comment: `"I have a structure array"` -- is that a plain-old array like `#define MAXS 128` then `Data huricanes[MAXS];` or is that a container, e.g.  `std::array<Data, 128>`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've defined hurricanes. If it is a C array, then you'll be wanting something like this:

```cpp
std::sort(hurricanes, hurricanes + counter, 
   [](const Data& a, const Data& b) { return std::strcmp(a.name, b.name) < 0; });
```

If however it is a std::vector or std::array, then...

```cpp
std::sort(hurricanes.begin(), hurricanes.end(), 
   [](const Data& a, const Data& b) { return std::strcmp(a.name, b.name) < 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what type of container you use ( I suggest to use std::vector), but you may do couple of nice things to make you life easier in this code.

First overload operators in Data structure like:

- `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Data& a_data)` for easily sending your struct to ostream (without need of encapsulating all it's members).
- `bool T::operator <(const T2 &b) const;` , `bool T::operator >(const T2 &b) const;` : for comparison in standard algorithms.

Take look at reference : [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)  You will write it only once but could use it in every part of program.

Second suggestion is to use std::sort algorithm to sort your data structure.

```
std::sort(hurricanes.begin(), hurricanes.end(), greater<Data>());
```

Syntax of your code will be much easier to understand and read for you wen you come back to project in 6 (or so) months.